# How to share variables & logging in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, distributed-system, stream-processing

Apache Flink offers the possibility to easy adapt operators. I am interested in the internal processings and want to log things that happen **inside** an operator. For this, a logger-object is handed out to the operator.

```java
public class LogSink extends RichSinkFunction<TaxiRide> {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("myLogger");

    public LogSink() {
        String msg = "Log Sink initialized";
        log.info(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void invoke(TaxiRide ride, Context context) throws Exception {
        log.info("Name: " + ride.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

In my main method on the main server (master), I initialize the operator. So, the message `"log sink initialized"` appears in my custom log file, as desired.

But the log messages (e.g. `"Name: TaxiRide324"`) that are logged within `invoke()` - which is called by a slave, e.g. another JVM - are written to in flinks `taskexecutor.log`.

I assume, this is because of the distributed processing. The TaskManager and JobManager have different JVMs and so the initialized logger is not used/seen by the JobManager in the execution. (But there is interestingly no `NullPointerExeption`...)

So my question is: **How could I achieve to share the objectss between initialization and execution of an inner class on a distributed flink cluster?**